# Web Scraping with Python without selenium in Freebsd

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have question possible `web scraping` without `selenium` in `freebsd`, then page loads data very slow?
I know are `beatiful soup` with `request`, but he just pick one request and not render java script who loads another request right?

Why not selenium? My `freebsd` server have just `1 gb ram` and `geckodriver` not working with one, need at least two, but i cant upgrade my server for it.

Page link is [here](https://www.verivox.de/stromvergleich/vergleich/#/?plz=10555&persons=on&usage=3500&bonus=OnlyCompliant&profile=H0&product=electricity&source=1&q=WzYsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMiwyMCwwLDEsNzQxMTIyLCI3MTA4NSIsMSwyNDAsMjQwLDM1MDAsMCwwLDAsOTk5LC0xLC0xLC0xLDAsMCwiVG90YWxDb3N0cyIsIkFzY2VuZGluZyIsIk5vbmUiLDM4LCJBbm51YWxDb3N0VmlldyIsMF0%3D&partnerid=1)

I need pick up first top 20 headers. My code for it in selenium (but i need make without selenium)

```
driver.get("https://www.verivox.de/stromvergleich/vergleich/#/?plz=10555&persons=on&usage=3500&bonus=OnlyCompliant&profile=H0&product=electricity&source=1&q=WzYsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMiwyMCwwLDEsNzQxMTIyLCI3MTA4NSIsMSwyNDAsMjQwLDM1MDAsMCwwLDAsOTk5LC0xLC0xLC0xLDAsMCwiVG90YWxDb3N0cyIsIkFzY2VuZGluZyIsIk5vbmUiLDM4LCJBbm51YWxDb3N0VmlldyIsMF0%3D&partnerid=1").text
time.sleep(3)
allheader=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(expected.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li[class='result-item'] .result-name-area>.result-name")))
for header in allheader:
    print("Header: " + header.text)
```

Maybe possible get data from json? Or with beatiful soup without request or something like what? Thank you for your help.

Edited
json link where are headers top 20 are in [here](https://www.verivox.de/api/energy/offers/electricity/postCode/10555/custom?partnerId=1) But they post it, so need season to get what

Comment: You might try the `requests-html` package https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/

Comment: "Slow" loading data is not caused by selenium - Page loads also slow if you call it directly, because it is calculating all the offers on demand. 

If there is an API you should use this first, else selenium is a very goog choice.

Comment: @James i cant install html request in my freebsd server.

Comment: @HedgeHog i dont say its selenium problem, but i cant solve what problem with selenium.